# Logback Appender for Webpage in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, logback, jamon

I have a maven and spring boot application which use logback.

This application is on some servers and the log files on this servers are stored only on this server.
Give it a tool/api which is free, can visualize the logs into a webpage and is easy to integrat with spring boot and maven?

I have try JAMon but it will not work with Spring boot (need to deploy a war file) because the spring boot application is a embedded application. Thanks for Help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on Kibana, search for ELK-Stack. You can easily run it using Docker. There is also a Maven lib for the logstash-forwarder.